# Sorting a hash in ruby by the third attribute value

Tags: ruby, datetime, hash

I am trying to sort this ruby hash using value3

```
map = [
  {:label=>"x", :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50", :value2=>"2019-03-03 19:50:50", :value3=>"00:38:00"},
  {:label=>"y", :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50", :value2=>"2019-03-04 07:47:28", :value3=>"12:34:38"},
  {:label=>"z", :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50", :value2=>"2019-03-03 22:24:13", :value3=>"03:11:23"}
]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to sort "this hash", but there are three hashes in your example, which one do you want to sort?

Comment: Also, Yes/No questions are not a good fit for [so], since neither answer is useful. "Is that possible" in *particular* is a *very bad* question, since the answer is almost always "Yes", but again, that answer is not particularly helpful. Plus, you should show your code, and explain where you are stuck, and what is the problem, otherwise, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sort_by` and pass a block, accessing in each element to the key `value3` (ascending by default):

```
map.sort_by { |element| element[:value3] }
# [{:label=>"x",
  :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50",
  :value2=>"2019-03-03 19:50:50",
  :value3=>"00:38:00"},
 {:label=>"z",
  :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50",
  :value2=>"2019-03-03 22:24:13",
  :value3=>"03:11:23"},
 {:label=>"y",
  :value1=>"2019-03-03 19:12:50",
  :value2=>"2019-03-04 07:47:28",
  :value3=>"12:34:38"}]
```

And to order same in descending ,

```
map.sort_by { |element| -element[:value3] }
```

Comment: Reversing the order via `-` only works for numerical values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @Stefan, that was kindly added by ray.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work because you're working with strings, not numbers.